# Attribute Errors - Python

Tags: python, hashlib

I have the following code snippets

```
thetype = raw_input("Please enter hash type. md5 or sha1")
hash_type = hashlib.thetype(word).hexdigest()
```

This returns the error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'thetype'
" I kind of understand why but I guess what I am really asking is, how can I fix this?

Comment: Just use hashlib.new(thetype, word).hexdigest()

Answer (score 2):

By using a dictionary (you can also use `getattr`, but that introduces the possibility of getting at other unrelated attributes).

```
d = {"md5" : hashlib.md5, "sha1" : hashlib.sha1}
hash_type = raw_input("Please enter hash type. md5 or sha1")
d[hash_type].hexdigest()
```

Also, `raw_input` already returns a `str`, so there's no need to call `str` again.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah I know about the str thing. I was screwing around haha. Didn't even realise I forgot to remove it

Answer (score 0):

```
import hashlib
thetype = raw_input("Please enter hash type. %r"%(hashlib.algorithms,))
# 2.7 or later... just catch the exception from .new(thetype) for older versions.
if thetype in hashlib.algorithms:
    print hashlib.new(thetype)('some data').hexdigest()
else:
    print "No Way!"
```